# armadillo linear sparse system solver using LAPACK and SuperLU

Tags: c++11, lapack, armadillo, blas

I tried to solve the sparse linear system using armadillo library.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<armadillo>
 using namespace std;
 using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int no_examples = 5000;
sp_mat A = sprandu<sp_mat>(no_examples,no_examples,0.7);
vec b = randu<vec>(no_examples);
wall_clock timer;
double t;
timer.tic();
vec x1 = spsolve(A, b,"superlu");
t= timer.toc();
cout<<"Elapsed time is:"<<t<<endl;
}
```

I compiled the program using `g++ demo.cpp  -O3 -I/usr/include/armadillo_bits -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lsuperlu -lopenblas -llapack`. The run time obtained with `superlu` option is about `8.5 seconds`. When the system system is solved with `LAPACK` option in `spsolve` [see here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#spsolve), run time is `4.01 seconds`. Can somebody explain why:

1. Solving the same system of equations takes longer by SuperLu than LAPACK? 
   my hunch is that they may be using different algorithms to solve the sparse linear system. Any other idea is welcomed!

Edit: I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4`.

Answer (score 0):

The density of the matrix is too big, making it almost dense.

The LAPACK's dense algorithm is able to use many of the vectorization and caching optimizations. The sparse algorithm is more complex than the dense LU factorization. It performs initializations and tries to make use of the sparsity of the matrix. If matrix is almost dense the simpler straight forward algorithm becomes faster.

I would expect SuperLU to have better performance for density values below 0.3-0.4.

Also storing a matrix with density=0.7 needs more memory in sparse format.
It needs to store values and their indexes.

Comment: I varied the density in [0,.7], however, the results are the same. SuperLU takes longer than LAPACK's dense LU factorization.

Comment: @chandresh that's strange. The SuperLU time does not change? Try to use matrix size 10,000.

Comment: The same conclusion as above.

Comment: By reading superlu docs, it says that superlu uses Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting (GEPP) for solving the sparse linear system. I have know idea about the time complexity of the GEPP compared to dense LU factorization used by LAPACK.